# how to generate sef urls manually without clicking the links in joomla site

Tags: joomla, joomla-sef-urls

we have sh404 sef component installed in my site.when we click any of the link on my site a sef url willl automatically generate and insert in to the databese.but i want to generate all the available sef urls for my site with out clicking all the links.how can i generate is there any way to ping all normal urls generated by me.

how can i generate sef urls manually for my site content.

Answer (score 0):

You can add sh404sef links using the backend config panel. You can add them under custom redirects.